# Question on using the word "perk"

Tags: vocabulary

I am writing the acknowledgement section of my thesis. Could someone please let me know if I am using the word "perk" correctly in the following?

> I want to thank my great friends in our lab, especially Ph.D. candidate Jason Wright for making the lab environment pleasant and rewarding. Coffee breaks with him were a great perk.

Should I use something else instead of "perk"? If perk is not commonly used, how can I say that coffee breaks with his were very useful? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use perk, it will be understood. It is not something the company provided which is what is normally understood by a perk: _Any monetary or other incidental benefit beyond salary_

Comment: *perk* in a coffee context may be taken as a pun.

Answer (score 4):

In casual usage, perk works well, in the sense they were an added benefit.However whether they were useful *per se*, is not clear. They could merely have been stress busters or fun.

'informative and fun' is something I can think of.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Should I say "Coffee breaks with him were fun" or "Coffee break with him was fun"?

Comment: were as you are talking about coffee breaks and not one coffee break

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't call a chat during a coffee break, *a perk*, even if it was work related. Saying that, it's clear what you mean and on the plus side it might be considered droll or tongue-in-cheek, hardly a negative thing. Since your comment will only be in the acknowledgement section of your thesis you could very well leave "perk" in.

However, the noun perk, is not usually used in that sense.

[WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=perk&sub=Search+WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=) has this to say:
*(an incidental benefit awarded for certain types of employment (especially if it is regarded as a right) "a limousine is one of the fringe benefits of the job"* It is short for [perquisite](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perquisite); *a payment or profit received in addition to a regular wage or salary, especially a benefit expected as one's due*

Normally we talk about the perks of a job, working for a company, holding a particular title or position.

> Having travelling costs covered by your company is a huge perk.
>   One of the perks of this job is that I get free health insurance.
>   He refused to hand back £30,000 worth of perks from his £201,000
>   retirement package

Alternatively, simply state that the coffee breaks shared with Jason Wright **were both entertaining and rewarding**, or words similar to that effect.

Comment: Downvoter, you're back! I've missed seeing those unexplained minuses 2s, it's been some time now. Were you sick, feeling better now? Good. :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you are trying to say is about the *incentives*. Something that brings additional value to you, except in your case, in a more social sense. It's the acknowledgement section, you are allowed to add a little bit of personal flavour in the writing. If you think that "*perk*" expresses the meaning you want, go ahead with it.

Maybe try this:

> I want to thank my great friends in our lab, especially Ph.D.
>   candidate Jason Wright for making the lab environment pleasant and
>   rewarding. Coffee breaks with him were a great ***incentive***.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the etymology of *perk* used as a synonym for bonus. Some dictionaries don't even list that meaning, so I assume it only made it's way into common usage relatively recently. It is very common in speech, though.

You are using it correctly in your acknowledgement. If you think it might be too casual, some synonyms for perk are *(added) bonus*, *(added) boon*.

What you write is a matter of your comfort and enthusiasm.

Comment: Perk is informal for *benefit*.

Comment: Perq or perk is a shortened form of perquisite: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perquisite ngram shows the perk variant picking up popularity from the late 70's on.